# ionic - read android assets file

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to read file in android assets subfolder, I had trying using file.checkDir and file.checkFile but it seems nothing is working. Here's some checkDir code :

```
  this.file.checkDir(
  this.file.dataDirectory, 'file:///android_asset/xl72.png').then(
    _ => alert('Directory exists')
  ).catch(err => alert('Directory doesn\'t exist'));
```

checkFile code :

```
this.file.checkFile(this.file.dataDirectory, 'xl72.png').then(
            (files) => {
              alert('files found ' + files)
            }
          ).catch (
            (err) => {
              alert(JSON.stringify(err))
            }
          );
```

Anyone know how to?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to open file from assets folder, the problem is its hard to find path to it. With this snippet i found it easy:

```
    this.file.listDir(this.file.applicationDirectory, '')
    .then( value => {
      console.log(value);
    });
```

result:

```
[{"isFile":true,"isDirectory":false,"name":"chrome_100_percent.pak","fullPath":"/chrome_100_percent.pak","filesystem":"<FileSystem: assets>","nativeURL":"file:///android_asset/chrome_100_percent.pak"},{"isFile":false,"isDirectory":true,"name":"fallback-locales","fullPath":"/fallback-locales/","filesystem":"<FileSystem: assets>","nativeURL":"file:///android_asset/fallback-locales/"},{"isFile":true,"isDirectory":false,"name":"icudtl.dat","fullPath":"/icudtl.dat","filesystem":"<FileSystem: assets>","nativeURL":"file:///android_asset/icudtl.dat"},{"isFile":false,"isDirectory":true,"name":"images","fullPath":"/images/","filesystem":"<FileSystem: assets>","nativeURL":"file:///android_asset/images/"},{"isFile":true,"isDirectory":false,"name":"natives_blob.bin","fullPath":"/natives_blob.bin","filesystem":"<FileSystem: assets>","nativeURL":"file:///android_asset/natives_blob.bin"},{"isFile":true,"isDirectory":false,"name":"resources.pak","fullPath":"/resources.pak","filesystem":"<FileSystem: assets>","nativeURL":"file:///android_asset/resources.pak"},{"isFile":true,"isDirectory":false,"name":"snapshot_blob_32.bin","fullPath":"/snapshot_blob_32.bin","filesystem":"<FileSystem: assets>","nativeURL":"file:///android_asset/snapshot_blob_32.bin"},{"isFile":true,"isDirectory":false,"name":"snapshot_blob_64.bin","fullPath":"/snapshot_blob_64.bin","filesystem":"<FileSystem: assets>","nativeURL":"file:///android_asset/snapshot_blob_64.bin"},{"isFile":false,"isDirectory":true,"name":"stored-locales","fullPath":"/stored-locales/","filesystem":"<FileSystem: assets>","nativeURL":"file:///android_asset/stored-locales/"},{"isFile":true,"isDirectory":false,"name":"webapk6.dex","fullPath":"/webapk6.dex","filesystem":"<FileSystem: assets>","nativeURL":"file:///android_asset/webapk6.dex"},{"isFile":true,"isDirectory":false,"name":"webapk_dex_version.txt","fullPath":"/webapk_dex_version.txt","filesystem":"<FileSystem: assets>","nativeURL":"file:///android_asset/webapk_dex_version.txt"},{"isFile":false,"isDirectory":true,"name":"webkit","fullPath":"/webkit/","filesystem":"<FileSystem: assets>","nativeURL":"file:///android_asset/webkit/"},{"isFile":false,"isDirectory":true,"name":"www","fullPath":"/www/","filesystem":"<FileSystem: assets>","nativeURL":"file:///android_asset/www/"}]
```

And after deep digging here is final result:

```
fullPath: "/www/assets/blink.bin"
```

Final conclusion. All files put into `project folder/www/assets` can be accessed with this path:
`this.file.listDir(this.file.applicationDirectory, 'www/assets')`

EDIT
even if i knew full path i couldnt open file with file opener2, then i decided to use this plugin to find and open files and it works great https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file